# Is it possible to view all active subscriptions

Tags: meteor

I have multiple subscriptions set up by various autoruns. It would be useful for debugging purposes to be able to view which subscriptions are active at any given time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Don't have an idea about "active" subscriptions.

But there is an object  `Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions` that stores information of all the subscriptions that have been subscribed till the given time.

```
    var subs = Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions; //all the subscriptions that have been subscribed.

    Object.keys(subs).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(subs[key]);   // see them in console.
    });
```

Not exactly what you want though.

Comment: `Meteor.default_connection` is undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: @Gobliins Use Meteor.connection

Answer (score 5):

Just as an addition to the above, we can organize them a bit in a way that makes it easier to check for multiple subscriptions etc.

```
//all the subscriptions that have been subscribed.
var subs = Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions; 
var subSummary = {};

// organize them by name so that you can see multiple occurrences
Object.keys(subs).forEach(function(key) {
  var sub = subs[key];
  // you could filter out subs by the 'active' property if you need to
  if (subSummary[sub.name] && subSummary[sub.name].length>0) {
    subSummary[sub.name].push(sub);
  } else {
    subSummary[sub.name] = [sub];
  }
});
console.log(subSummary);
```

Note you can see the 'ready' state, as well as params used in the subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the info!